# Is there a way to check if specific point (X,Y) is in the SVG element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

What I need to do is to understand if mouse leaves SVG object (path, i.e it is not a rectangular - can't use just offset, not a circular - can't use radius and center position, etc. ). I can not use mouse leave/enter events because I have a pointer for mouse that is always above all elements. Obviously I also can't just use elementFromPoint - because it gives the top layer element.

So the question:
Is there a way to understand if coordinates (X,Y) are in the specific element $("#element").

UPD:

I uploaded my current code to my website http://pekap.co/example/ 
I didn't create jsfiddle because I have SVG object to ebmed.
There you can find my JS, svg object I use, etc.

If you go to the svg object it changes its color and pointer appears (orange circle). The goal is to change color of the SVG area whenever we leave it/ enter it and display orange circle under mouse only inside SVG area.

Whereas currently I can accomplish on one of goals (either one with different code)

UPD 2.

Erik Dahlström gave almost perfect solution for me: set pointer-events to none in CSS. I will go for this now, however to make my day perfect it would be great if there was a way to detect when any part of circle is out of the SVG area.

Comment: Would it work for you to check the bounding box of an element (`.getBBox()`)?

Comment: Do you have an example (a code example if possible!) of what you're trying to achieve? There might be a simpler way.

Comment: Unfortunately my object is not rectangular so I guess .getBox is not appropriate. I uploaded files to my website and inserted link. Hope it is now more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow what you mean, the pointer is the little circle that follows the mouse?

If so, then just make that circle have `pointer-events: none` and it will be "transparent" to mouse events. Note that webkit/safari/chrome/blink doesn't yet support `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` so you'll likely need some scriptbased workaround (not sure if D3 does this already).

It should also be possible to do a solution based on using a CSS `:hover` rule on the path element. Set some property to some value on hover, and then check with `getComputedStyle` what the property is currently set to on the path element.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, pointer-events:none; works perfectly. Spent 20 hours to find such simple solution. Mouseenter and mouseleave work for me in webkit though. Why would you say that they don't? I am also wondering if there a way to check when the part of small circle leaves the area of SVG path?

Comment: Yes, very recent webkit versions support mouseenter/mouseleave, see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18930 and for chromium/blink http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236215. If you want to verify that the events are fired, see e.g this test page: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/mouseover.html

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to to create a image map of the area, its a lot of work but this seems to be what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/

```
<area shape="poly" name="dip" coords="253,102, 277,100, 280,105, 290,107, 295,111, 304,130, 290,140, 287,147, 240,157, 238,159, 227,153, 203,146, 198,125, 200,116, 214,102, 231,102" href="#">
```

this fiddle is from [image mapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#vegetables)

Comment: This probably could be a solution, but I was looking for something simpler. (see marked answer)